# How to custom TextView Android - settext()

Tags: textview

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="20dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have 2 strings:

```
"Text one here"
"Text two here"
```

How to custom a textview has 2 lines, line1 only for String1, and line2 for only String2, 
if width of textview not enough will show "..."

like:

```
Text one...
Text two...
```

because my textview width is too short, and I want show 2 string as it posible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:maxLines, android:lines` properties in your TextView as follow:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxLines="2"
android:lines="2"
/>
```

after that you can pass `textView.setText()` to multiline string.

Comment: but my textview width is too short, so it can not show full String

Comment: my textview width is too short, and I want show 2 string as it posible,

Comment: line 1 only for string1, line2 for only string2, width not enough will show "..."

Answer (score 0):

count the total no of letters can fit inside in a single line inside textview.In my case it was 45.now if the length of first string is greater then 45.Add 45 spaces in place of first string.like this

```
mtextView.setText(s1);
mtextView.setText("\n"+s2);

if(s1.length>45)
  s1="";

mtextView.setText(s1);
mtextView("\n"+s2);
```

jst count the total no of letters hold by a single line of textview. and the rest of work will be done by this code.

Comment: s1 and s2 will auto change every day. width of textview can not be change.

Comment: 'width of s1' always longer than 'width of textview'

Comment: user will see 's1 and s2' on 1 textview. User do not need see full s1 and s2, just a part of them.